# How do I access my react component props from a fineuploader const callback outside the class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fine-uploader

I'm trying to access a react component's props after react-fine-uploader finishes uploading files and fires a callback. However, the uploader is outside the component and I can't seem to access the props of the component from the callback function.

```js
import React from 'react';
// other imports

const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({
  options: {
    request: {
      endpoint: '/upload',
    },
    callbacks: {
      onAllComplete: function(id, fileName, response) {
        console.log("Fineuploader: onAllComplete")
        // trying to access component props here
      }
    }
  }
 })
 
 class myReactComponent extends React.Component {

 }
 
 export default myReactComponent
```

Comment: Wrap your uploader in a function and pass values as arguments or move the uploader in the component

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it inside your component:

```
import React from 'react';
// other imports
class myReactComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({
         options: {
            request: {
            endpoint: '/upload',
            },
            callbacks: {
               onAllComplete: function(id, fileName, response) {
               console.log("Fineuploader: onAllComplete")
               // you should be able to access props here
               }
            }
         }
      })
   }
 }

 export default myReactComponent
```

You could also put this in render instead of the constructor:

```
class myReactComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
      const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({
         options: {
            request: {
            endpoint: '/upload',
            },
            callbacks: {
               onAllComplete: function(id, fileName, response) {
               console.log("Fineuploader: onAllComplete")
               // you should be able to access this.props here
               }
            }
         }
      })
      ....
      return <>
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

after doing some more digging I found I can regester a callback handler inside the component using the following:

```js
    uploader.on('onAllComplete', (id, name, response) => {
      //
    })
```

So the const is still outside the class, but I can access the callback inside.